# CKEditor: HowTo destroy instance on blur?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, jquery-events

I have a single html page with multiple `div` elements on it. Each time a user clicks on on a `div`, it is replaced with an `CKEditor` on the fly:

```
$('.editable').click(function() {
    editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this);
});
```

Now, if the CKEditor instance loses its focus (blur event), I need to post the content to a separate script via ajax (if something changed) and destroy this instance:

```
$('.editable').click(function() {
    editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this);
    editor.on('blur', function(e)
    {
        if (e.editor.checkDirty())
           // get data with e.editor.getData() and do some ajax magic 

        e.editor.destroy();
    });
});
```

But this example won't work because, I don't know why, `destory()` will be called before `checkDirty()`. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

How about if you put the `destroy()` inside the `if()` statement? You could have an else clause that invokes destroy if nothing has changed. If something has changed, you can invoke `destroy()` within the if clause once the data has been transfered.

```
$('.editable').click(function() {
  editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this);
  editor.on('blur', function(e)
  {
    if (e.editor.checkDirty()) {
       // get data with e.editor.getData() and do some ajax magic
       if ( dataTransferComplete ) {
         e.editor.destroy();
       }

     } else {
       e.editor.destroy();
     }
  });
});
```

Or you could check a variable before invoking `destroy()`. Set that variable to true after the data transfer has been completed and in the else clause, that way `destroy()` won't be invoked until you've checked for changes and transfered any updated data.

```
$('.editable').click(function() {
  editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this);
  editor.on('blur', function(e)
  {
    var okToDestroy = false;

    if (e.editor.checkDirty()) {
       // get data with e.editor.getData() and do some ajax magic
       okToDestroy = true;
     } else {
       okToDestroy = true;
     }

    if (okToDestroy )
      e.editor.destroy();

  });
});
```

This is an outline, I haven't tested the code, but if shows the concept.

Be Well,
Joe