# Loading Multiple CKEditors is Slow

Tags: ckeditor, page-load-time

I have a lot of ckeditors on one web page for students to enter their data. I have a lot of ckeditors because each one is for one variable. Unfortunately, an input text field is too small for the data requested. The problem is that it takes too long for the web page to load and sometimes the web page hangs.

I'm currently loading almost 425 editors.

Here's an example of my code for three:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(window).load(function () {
        CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
            var jqScript = document.createElement('script');
            var bsScript = document.createElement('script');

            jqScript.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js';
            bsScript.src = 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js';

            var editorHead = ev.editor.document.$.head;
            editorHead.appendChild(jqScript);
            editorHead.appendChild(bsScript);
        });

        // Load CK Editor
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
            contentsCss: 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        });
        // Load CK Editor
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor2', {
            contentsCss: 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        });
        // Load CK Editor
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor3', {
            contentsCss: 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'
        });
    });//]]>
</script>
```

I followed the **[performance guidelines](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-Loading-performance-details)** on ckeditor, searched Stackoverflow for answers and it still isn't working. I even have the ckeditor toolbar minimized to just one row. I figure there has to be a way to load the ckeditors without having to load ALL the ckeditors and the contentCss when the page loads, but when the ckeditor is needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes according to @Roman answer, you should only initialize ckeditor when the input field is click then if it loses focus, destroys it.

```
$('.editable').click(function() {
  editor = CKEDITOR.replace(this);
  editor.on('blur', function(e)
  {
    var okToDestroy = false;

    if (e.editor.checkDirty()) {
       // get data with e.editor.getData() and do some ajax magic
       okToDestroy = true;
     } else {
       okToDestroy = true;
     }

    if (okToDestroy )
      e.editor.destroy();

  });
});
```

Here `.editable` is your input field. Reference: [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485621/ckeditor-howto-destroy-instance-on-blur)

Comment: Thank you Reinmar, Roman and truongnm! I have finally figured it out from your advise and it works. I also added .block {

    width: 350px !important;
    height: 150px;
    

} to control the width and height of the ckeditor.

Answer (score 4):

> but the total number of ckeditors on the web page is almost 425.

Have you ever tried to open any application 425 times at the same time? 425 tab in your browser, 425 Wordpads, 425 of whatever? I don't think so.

So the answer is very short - you're doing it wrong. You should not initialize all editors at once. Load them on demand when needed and destroy when not needed. User can't edit 425 text at the same time anyway.

The longer answer is that [classic editor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed) is the heaviest one because it uses `<iframe>`. So when you initialize 425 you initialize 425 iframes. [Inline editors](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) are much lighter. There's also a [divarea](http://ckeditor.com/addon/divarea) plugin which makes the classic editor use inline editable element instead of `<iframe>`, so it's lighter too.

But the answer is still - you're doing it wrong.

Comment: "Load them on demand when needed and destroy when not needed." Are there examples to look at to learn? The only example I saw on the web isn't working -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896892/ckeditor-inline-instance-fails-to-reload-after-its-destroyed (http://jsfiddle.net/22A6F/)

Comment: @Reinmarm, I have followed the inline editor approach and it increases the page loading time considerably for the ckeditors. Now, the only problem I have is the contentedible="true" is turned into contentedible="false" when I click the 186 ckeditor and the ckeditor does not load at all, but if I delete some of the previous inline editors listed - the ckeditors that didn't work now work, so its probably a number thing in the ckeditor.js file. Any help would be appreciated. Link with images: http://1drv.ms/1HdvF8X

Answer (score 2):

The best way to approach it is to activate each editor instance on focus or via a button. Or even cooler would be to edit the text in a popup or a popover, this way it can be destroyed when the html is saved releasing the resources.

Also include your script files into the header of HTML rather than loading them dynamically (way slower and bad for caching).

Comment: With a similar editor and project, I put a pencil icon for edit and activated the editor on click of the pencil. In any case, here is an example to support this answer: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/CKEditor-v4-Double-Click-to-Initiate-Editor