# I want two ckeditor in the same page

Tags: ckeditor

I use Ckeditor but I want use two ckeditor in the same page

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
<textarea name="repondre" id="repondre" style="width:100%" rows=2 COLS=40></textarea>  
<input type="submit" value="Répondre" name="submitComment"/><br/>
</form>
<script>
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'repondre',
 {
 height: 50,
 customConfig : '/editor/custom/basic_config.js'
 });
         
</script>
```

and the second form

```html
<form method="POST" action="">
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" style="width:100%" rows=2 COLS=40></textarea>  
<input type="submit" value="Répondre" name="submitComment"/><br/>
</form>
<script>
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'comment',
 {
 height: 50,
 customConfig : '/editor/custom/full_config.js'
 });
         
</script>
```

but it's doesn't work because I have only the firt form appear

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24169476/4229270

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the jquery adapter (you have to add it as a plugin too).

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery